# SQLite on iOS get previous day's records - not working

Tags: ios, sqlite

I'm trying to get all records from my SQLite DB within the last day.

I've tried the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM timeTable WHERE STOPDATE >= date('now', '-1 day')
```

However this gives me all records dating back many days.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
SELECT * from timeTable where STOPDATE = (select max(STOPDATE) from timeTable WHERE STOPDATE < DATE('now') )
```